# Is Extended permission in Facebook need to be record by developer?

Tags: actionscript-3, facebook

I am developing a Flash-based application for Facebook. I read many comment that the application need to pop-up dialog for user to decide to extend their permission.

The question is, who will record those decision? Facebook or the developer? because it might be a problem if user is asking the court for their privacy.

Answer (score 0):

Teerasej, I can't clearly understand what your question is about, but I'll do my best to answer. Please consider clarifying what you mean, so that people will have a better chance of helping you out.

Firstly, if I understand correctly, you're writing an application that works within Facebook, providing some service for the users.

Now, when you must ask the user to grant permission to the application to do something, I believe that call must be handled within Facebook, not in your application. In the Facebook Developer wiki, you can see that the calls to prompt a user for extended permissions are handled by the Facebook platform itself. Here's the section that explains how to do this: http://wiki.developers.facebook.com/index.php/Extended_permissions#Prompting_Users_to_Grant_Extended_Permissions.

It would appear that these calls work within the Facebook markup language, FBML, and possibly their other supported languages (FQL, XFBML, etc) for their appropriate uses. There is a library provided by Adobe for interfacing with Facebook, which you may find here hosted on Google Code: http://code.google.com/p/facebook-actionscript-api/. That library might be able to help you perform some of these calls natively within ActionScript.

I hope this helps.